# Database table constraints query

Tags: database

Can a relational table have constraints related to another table? If yes, please provide an example also

Answer (score 0):

Yes, think of foreign key constraint. Foreign key constraint is related to another table.
For example, consider following table

1. Address (Addressid (PK), AddressLine1, City, State_cd (FK))
2. State (State_cd(PK), State_name)

Note here that State_cd which is in Address table is related to another table (State).

Hope this is clear